# Variable length free list

Tags: algorithm

The concept of [free list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) is commonly used for re-using space so if I have a file full of fixed-length values and I delete one, I put it on a free list. Then when I need to insert new value I take one from the list and put it on that spot.

However I am a bit confused as to how to implement a free list for values that are variable length. If I delete the value and I put the position and its length on the free list, how do I retrieve the "best" candidate for a new value?

Using plain list will be `O(n)` time complexity. Using a tree (with length as key) would make that `log(n)`. Is there anything better that would give `O(1)`?

Comment: There are many different options, from your basic, but simple to code, linear list, as you already mentioned, to a "list" that consists of a series of hash buckets of balanced trees to segregate different sized allocations, which is considerably more difficult to code correctly, and many other options in between. It all depends on exactly what you need and how much work you're willing to expend to get it - a common theme in programming...

Comment: @twalberg The use case is roughly this: I have a graph in which each node (and edge) can have arbitrary number of key-value pairs associated with each of them. And I need to store these in a file so I can a) have O(1) access of values based on node+key, b) have a way to know all keys associated with a node. So for a) hash table would work nicely but it doesn't allow b). Hence I need to somehow store it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a hash table! So you have a big hashtable containing the sizes of the free blocks as keys and the values are arrays holding pointers to blocks of the corresponding sizes. So each time you free a block:

```
hash[block.size()].append(block.address())
```

And each time you allocate a free block:

```
block = hash[requested_size].pop()
```

The problem with this method is there are too many possible block sizes. Therefore the hash will fill up with millions of keys, wasting enormous amounts of memory.

So instead you can have a list and iterate it to find a suitable block:

```
for block in blocks:
    if block.size() >= requested_size:
        return blocks.remove(block)
```

Memory efficient but slow because you might have to scan through millions of blocks.

So what you do is you combine these two methods. If you set your allocation quanta to 64, then a hash containing 256 size classes can be used for all allocations up to 64 * 256 = 16 kb. Blocks larger than that you store in a tree which gives you O(log N) insertion and removal.